# Android getting Error inserting to databse and code 19: constraint failed

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i'm wrote simple `DataBaseHelper` to use SQlite in android. after create class as :

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        private static String DB_PATH                   = "";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME       = "tsms";

        private static String RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE      = "ReceiveFields";

        private static final String COLUMN_ID           = "id";

        private static final String COLUMN_LASTID       = "lastId";

        private static final String COLUMN_SMSNUMBER    = "smsNumber";

        private static final String COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER = "mobileNumber";

        private static final String COLUMN_SENDERNAME   = "senderName";

        private static final String COLUMN_SMSBODY      = "smsBody";

        private static final String COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE  = "receiveDate";

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

        /* UPDATE DATABASE_CREATE FIELD*/

        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER  UNIQUE , "
            + COLUMN_LASTID       + " INTEGER  UNIQUE , "
            + COLUMN_SMSNUMBER    + " VARCHAR  UNIQUE , "
            + COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER + " VARCHAR , "
            + COLUMN_SENDERNAME   + " VARCHAR , "
            + COLUMN_SMSBODY      + " TEXT , "
            + COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE  + " VARCHAR , PRIMARY KEY (" + COLUMN_ID + ", " + COLUMN_LASTID + ", " + "))";

    private Context context;

    public  DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    // Adding new fields
    public void addToReceived(ReceiveFields fields) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COLUMN_LASTID,       fields.getLastId());           // ReceiveFields last ID

        values.put(COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER, fields.getMobileNumber());     // ReceiveFields Mobile Number

        values.put(COLUMN_SENDERNAME,   fields.getSenderName());       // ReceiveFields Mobile Number

        values.put(COLUMN_SMSBODY,      fields.getSmsBody());          // ReceiveFields Mobile Number

        values.put(COLUMN_SMSNUMBER,    fields.getSmsNumber());        // ReceiveFields Mobile Number

        values.put(COLUMN_MOBILENUMBER, fields.getMobileNumber());     // ReceiveFields Mobile Number

        values.put(COLUMN_RECEIVEDATE,  String.valueOf(fields.getReceiveDate())); // ReceiveFields Mobile Number

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(RECEIVE_FIELDS_TABLE, null, values);

        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
}
```

I get Error Inserting to database with this way:

```
db.addToReceived(new ReceiveFields(

                            Long.valueOf(str1[0]),

                            str1[1],

                            str1[2],

                            URLDecoder.decode(str1[3], "UTF-8"),

                            URLDecoder.decode(str1[4], "UTF-8"),

                            ct.getGregorianDate()));
```

`Log.i` Result:

```
 29904757    30007227    00120504001    00120504001     sssasaS     2014/8/3
```

full LogCate Result:

```
08-28 06:35:29.974    2698-2698/ir.tsms E/Database﹕ Error inserting lastId=29904755 receiveDate=2014/8/3 senderName=09127574751 mobileNumber=09127574751 smsNumber=30007227 smsBody=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
            at ir.tsms.DataBase.DatabaseHandler.addToReceived(DatabaseHandler.java:96)
            at ir.tsms.wsdl.TSMS.getReceivedSMS(TSMS.java:141)
            at ir.tsms.Receive.ResivedSMS.getResivedSMS(ResivedSMS.java:41)
            at ir.tsms.Receive.ResivedSMS.<init>(ResivedSMS.java:36)
            at ir.tsms.Activities.DashboardActivity.onTabSelected(DashboardActivity.java:160)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplBase.selectTab(ActionBarImplBase.java:486)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplBase.addTab(ActionBarImplBase.java:410)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplBase.addTab(ActionBarImplBase.java:401)
            at ir.tsms.Activities.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:68)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`at ir.tsms.wsdl.TSMS.getReceivedSMS(TSMS.java:141)` line is :

```
db.addToReceived(new ReceiveFields(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these things, it may causes by these reason:

1- you did not add `COLUMN_ID` to `values` so it is null.

2-`COLUMN_ID` and `COLUMN_LASTID` are not `UNIQUE` `(clear your database or android app data , maybe it stored in your db first time you ran it and now again you want to add you can not because it is not unique now, every time you run, your db is in memory and it is not clread, in order to clear it you must remove app data or run delete SQL statement)`

so i suggest you to see your DB file, if you use eclipse try this:

http://www.tylerfrankenstein.com/browse-android-emulator-sqlite-database-eclipse

3-`COLUMN_ID` and `COLUMN_LASTID` are not int i mean `fields.getLastId()` may return `String`

check exactly your table defination and your values to insert !!!

Comment: `COLUMN_ID` must be null for `UNIQUE` and `AutoIncrement`

Comment: i know but you did not add `AutoIncrement`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to insert `null` as `smsBody` but your table does not allow you to do this as it has `NOT NULL` constraint for this column.

Comment: how to change `+ COLUMN_SMSBODY      + " TEXT NOT NULL  check(typeof(" + COLUMN_SMSBODY + ") = 'text') , "` to correct method as accept null

Comment: remove `NOT NULL` statement i suppose?

Comment: Updated post `DATABASE_CREATE field` sir. not resolve problem